# What is a pointer to member template argument?

Tags: c++, templates

It seams that template parameters can be also be `pointer to members`. What does this mean and can someone give an example when this is used?

Comment: A google search will be more productive. StackOverflow is for specific programming questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rather silly example:
    struct foo
    {
     void action1() { }
    void action2() { }
    };

```
template<void (foo::*pfn)()>
struct bar
{
    bar(foo & f) { (f.*pfn)();
}
};
void qux()
{
foo f;
bar<&foo::action1>(f);
bar<&foo::action2>(f);
}
```

It can also be used with compile-time metaprogramming where you can for example xtract the return type of a function:

```
template<typename Fn>
struct return_type;
template<typename C, typename RetType, typename ... Args>
struct return_type<RetType (C::*)(Args...)>
{
  typedef RetType type;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In c/c++, variables can use pointers to reference either a value, or a pointer to that value. Methods can do the same exact thing!

Putting this into practice:

```
#include <iostream>

int foo() {
  return 4;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << foo() << "\n";
  std::cout << (int)*foo;
}
```

Should output the value returned by the function, then on a separate line the address of the function itself. This could look something like:

```
4
4198528
```

The second value is the memory location of my method foo within my computer's RAM (and obviously the first is the value returned by the function).

Comment: The question is about template arguments that are pointers to members (of a class or structure)

Comment: Note that `(int)*foo` is undefined behavior. Especially on 64-bit machines where `sizeof(void*) > sizeof(int)`. There's `intptr_t` for this.